# PCI express 2.0 vs 3.0

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

If I were to used a video card that is PCIE 3.0 on my motherboard which has PCIE 2.0 (its backwards compatible) will there

1. Be any noticeable difference?
2. Would buying a decent video card mean't for PCIE 3.0 (GTX 660) be a waste of money versus buying another one that is PCIE 2.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Be any noticeable difference?

In most cases: No.

PCI-e v3 can be twice as fast as PCI-e v2, but most cards are not bandwidth limited. Therefor lowering the bandwidth has only a small (4%-ish) performance penalty.

There are exceptions to this. E.g. when using GPCPU/OpenCL, where the lower latency of PCI-e v3 helps. Or when you are using extreme resolutions (say 5760x1920) and high settings in games. But in most cases there will be no noticeable difference.

> Would buying a decent video card mean't for PCIE 3.0 (GTX 660) be a waste of
>   money versus buying another one that is PCIE 2.0 ?

Only if the v3 capable card is more expensive then an equally performing card which uses PCI-e v2 and if you do not intend to keep the card when you buy your next computer.

Disclaimer: All this assumes that you use an x16 slot. If you put the card in x4 or x1 slots then the speed difference between v2 and v3 gets more pronounced.